# How can I search an HTML table for only an exact match of my input in the search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, search, html-table, exact-match

I am currently using the code below to create a single-column search for an HTML table on a website.  At the moment, when I type something in to the search bar, the code returns every row that has content that contains the thing I searched for anywhere within it.  For example (I'm using this for movie ratings), when I type "G" in to the search bar, I get back everything rated G, but also everything rated PG or PG-13.  Is there a way that I can adapt this code to return only results that are exact matches for my search?  In other words, is there a way to change things so that when I search for "G" (or "g"), I only get back my G-rated movies and not anything rated PG or PG-13?

Thank you!

The Current Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function searchRows(tblId) {
var tbl = document.getElementById(tblId);
var headRow = tbl.rows[0];
var arrayOfHTxt = new Array();
var arrayOfHtxtCellIndex = new Array();

for (var v = 0; v < headRow.cells.length; v++) {
 if (headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]) {
 var Htxtbox = headRow.cells[v].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  if (Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') != '') {
    arrayOfHTxt.push(Htxtbox.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
    arrayOfHtxtCellIndex.push(v);
  }
 }
}

for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {

    tbl.rows[i].style.display = 'table-row';

    for (var v = 0; v < arrayOfHTxt.length; v++) {

        var CurCell = tbl.rows[i].cells[arrayOfHtxtCellIndex[v]];

        var CurCont = CurCell.innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");

        var reg = new RegExp(arrayOfHTxt[v] + ".*", "i");

        if (CurCont.match(reg) == null) {

            tbl.rows[i].style.display = 'none';

       }

    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly use `toUpperCase()`

then you can just use `===` if you only want to distinguish `G, PG, PG-13, R, NC-17`, you dont